# How to solve Jacobian elliptical function in python

Tags: python, function, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, elliptic-curve

I know how to solve in Mathematica with `EllipticF`:

```
EllipticF[ζI[P], k2[P]] - EllipticF[ζr[P, r], k2[P]]
```

That's basically what i want to do in Python. I've tried many thing to use such as the function `scipy.special.ellipj`, but it returns a list and i want a number. Please, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: Maybe [this blogpost of John Cook](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/10/12/jacobi-function-nomenclature/) is useful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to Mathematica's [`EllipticF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticF.html) in SciPy is [`scipy.special.ellipkinc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipkinc.html).

For example, in Wolfram Alpha, [`EllipticF(3/4, 1/10)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EllipticF%283%2F4%2C+1%2F10%29) gives the numerical value `0.7564213553633020688976920...`.

With SciPy,

```
In [49]: from scipy.special import ellipkinc                                                                                               

In [50]: ellipkinc(0.75, 0.1)                                                                                                              
Out[50]: 0.7564213553633021
```

(I don't know what the arguments are that you are passing to `EllipticF`, so I can't help you with those.)